# Can drupal router handle PUT requests?

Tags: drupal, rest

I have a module that will be using some restfulness and i'd like to know if drupal's menu router handles PUT requests without problem...?

Comment: You got me :p actually i found that the rest server module seems to do deal with it just fine. So drupal doesn't "reject" PUT requests :)
May be i should delete this question...?

Comment: This is a valid question (+1), so no need to delete it (others may look for exactly this information) - just answer your own question with your findings and accept that answer (after the grace period).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After doing some research i found that Nothing stops you from handling PUT requests on Drupal. Actually i looked at the code in [rest server module](http://drupal.org/project/rest_server) and it seems to handle it without problem. Just inspect the php `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` as you'd normally do.

Note: Answered my own question and keeping it as per @Henrik Opel comment